# How to use shared Preferences in static method

Tags: java, android

here this is my static method

```
public static void messageHandler(final MessageMO messageMo) {

        UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1;
                Log.e("messageHandler", messageMo.getEventTitle());
                ChatMO chatMO = new ChatMO();
                chatMO.setMessage(messageMo.getMessage());
                chatMO.setSelf(0);
                chatMO.setFromName(messageMo.getfromUserName());
                chatMO.setDate(messageMo.getDate());
                chatMO.setEvent_id(messageMo.getEventId());
                Log.e("handler", "eventid" + chatMO.getEvent_id());
                Log.e("handler", "date" + chatMO.getDate());
                listChatMessageObjectses.add(chatMO);
                Log.e("handler", "listmessage" + listChatMessageObjectses);

                    }
        });
    }
```

here i have to store the value of listChatMessageObjects into shared preferences how to do it thanks in advance

Comment: Pass Context object to messageHandler, Using this object access SharedPreference.

Comment: But I dont think you can put List into shared preference. There is a mximum option to put StringSet apart from that there is no method you can use to put List. Consider storing it in sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the method signature to receive a `Context`:

```
public static void messageHandler(final Context context, final MessageMO messageMo)
```

And then open the preferences using [`Context.getSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)).

PS: `listChatMessageObjects` sounds like a lot of data.. consider to use a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) for storing a lot of records.